# Unable to send Post to telegram bot api on firefox extension but chrome extension can

Tags: ajax, firefox, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, telegram-bot

I trying to send Post request on firefox extension with different method,such as

```
$.ajax({
            url:'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage',
            method:'POST',
            data:{chat_id:chat,text:text},
            success:function(){
                alert('your message has been sent!');
            }
        });
```

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", 'https://api.telegram.org/bot742161305:AAGQkD-llRhtKuZm7F5XxZrTZfHpI6cB7jw/sendMessage', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xhr.send(JSON.stringify({
        chat_id:id,
        text:'aaa'
    }));
```

```
fetch('http://api.telegram.org/bot742161305:AAGQkD-llRhtKuZm7F5XxZrTZfHpI6cB7jw/sendMessage?chat_id=id&text=content')
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

but those method are not working, i try those all of them on tempermonkey,it's all work!
Beside, the same code can run on google extension,100% work. 
I am stuck for a long time.

Please help me to solve the question,thank you very much!

Here are my 
manifest.json

```
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      "<all_urls>",
    ],
```

Comment: Replace `web_accessible_resources` with `permissions`.

Comment: OMG,it's work! Thank you so much!